# Query to get tables having indexing in a particular database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone provide me the query in sql server to extract the tables that have been done indexing, for a particular database....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear. This will return all tables with at least one index.

```
select DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)  
from sys.indexes 
where type<>0
```

Or for SQL Server 2000

```
select DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(id)   
from sysindexes 
where indid<>0
```

Comment: Upvoting.  He's on SQL 2000, so you gave the only answer that will work for him.

Answer (score 2):

```
select object_name(object_id),* from sys.indexes where type <> 0
```

This will return you all the indexes available in your database. But beware, it also lists the system tables.

Comment: This will also include tables with no indexes at all (heaps). These have a `type` of `0`

Answer (score 1):

The [sys.indexes DMV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx) should have what you're looking for:

```
SELECT TableName = object_name(Object_Id)
     , IndexName = Name
     , IndexType = Type_Desc

 FROM sys.indexes
```

The Type_Desc column will tell you whether you're looking at a heap, a clustered index, or a non-clustered index.

Joining to sys.tables will limit the results to user tables and leave out system tables:

```
SELECT TableName = st.Name
     , IndexName = si.name
     , IndexType = si.type_desc
  FROM SYS.indexes si
  JOIN SYS.tables st
    ON si.object_id  = st.object_id
```

Comment: sys.indexes is invalid object..thats what sqserver is telling

Comment: Which version are you using?  The sys.indexes queries will work in 2005 and 2008.

Comment: @Srivastava What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you logged in with sufficient permissions?

Comment: Martin's post contains a SQL Server 2000 version that should work for you.